# If clauses between where composition to laravel collect

Tags: laravel, collect

Situation:

```
$post_1 = 'john'; 
$post_2 = 30;

$arr = array(['name'=>'john','number'=>70],['name'=>'clark','number'=>50]); 
$collection = collect($arr);

if($post_1 == 'john')
{
     $collection->where('name',$post_1); 
}
if($post_2 == 70)
{
     $collection->where('number',$post_2);
}
var_dump($collection->all());
```

But this doesn't work. I want to include filters but it depends on the post parameters to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `when`

```
$result= $collection->when(($post_1=="john"), function ($collection)use($post_1) {

        return $collection->where('name',$post_1);

    })->when(($post_2 == 70), function ($collection)use($post_2) {

        return $collection->where('number',$post_2);

    })->all();


dd($result);
```

or

```
$collection->when(($post_1=="john"), function ($collection)use($post_1) {

            return $collection->where('name',$post_1);

        })->when(($post_2 == 70), function ($collection)use($post_2) {

            return $collection->where('number',$post_2);

        });
    
    
    dd($collection->all());
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-when